# Merge 2 lines in .CSV file using StreamReader

Tags: c#, csv, streamreader

I am currently trying to merge some lines in a .csv file. The file follows a specific format which is split by "," and the last element uses \n ascii code. This means the last element gets put onto a new line and i return an array with only one Element. I am looking to merge this element with the line above it.

So my line would be:

```
192.168.60.24, ACD_test1,86.33352, 07/12/2014 13:33:13, False, Annotated, True,"Attribute1
Attribute 2
Attribute 3"
192.168.60.24, ACD_test1,87.33352, 07/12/2014 13:33:13, False, Annotated, True
```

Is it possible to merge/join the new line attributes with the line above?

My code is shown below:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@path));
                string line1 = reader.ReadLine();
                if (line1.Contains("Server, Tagname, Value, Timestamp, Questionable, Annotated, Substituted"))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        List<string> listPointValue = new List<string>();
                        var line = reader.ReadLine();
                        var values = line.Split(',');

                        if (values.Count() < 2)
                        {
                            //*****Trying to Add Attribute to listPointValue.ElememtAt(0) here******
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            foreach (string value in values)
                            {
                            listPointValue.Add(value);
                            }
                            allValues.Add(listPointValue);
                        }
                    }
                   // allValues.RemoveAt(0);
                    return allValues;
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to read the next line before you do the allValues.Add. That way you can decide whether to add the previous line to allValues (starting a new line). This gives you an idea of what I mean:

```
var reader = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(@path));
string line1 = reader.ReadLine();
if (line1.Contains("Server, Tagname, Value, Timestamp, Questionable, Annotated, Substituted"))
{
    List<string> listPointValue = new List<string>();

    // Add first line to listPointValue
   var line = reader.ReadLine();
   var values = line.Split(',');
   foreach (string value in values)
   {
        listPointValue.Add(value);
   }

   while (!reader.EndOfStream)
   {
        // Read next line
        line = reader.ReadLine();
        values = line.Split(',');

        // If next line is a full line, add the previous line and create a new line
        if (values.Count() > 1)
        {
            allValues.Add(listPointValue);
            listPointValue = new List<string>();
        }

        // Add values to line
        foreach (string value in values)
        {
             listPointValue.Add(value);
        }
    }
    allValues.Add(listPointValue);
}
```